# max date filter in joining tables sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following ERD
[image]

I want to have a report like this

```
student_name | student_lastname | class_level | class_month | academic_calendar_start_date
```

where it shows the last class taken by every student.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. You need to show what you have managed to achieve on your own and then ask a specific  question about you code

Answer (score 0):

Try to join the table using **JOIN**  so you can get the data what you have asked

Comment: Thank you. I'll try